# boot from usb thumb drive: the installed (octave) pkg not there and forever after, on subsequent boot!

Tags: installation, usb

I successfully installed and used Octave from a USB thumb drive for a Toshiba 205 netbook.
Everything was fine.
Then I quit and re-booted.
Octave had disappeared from the launcher.
And, I can't find relevant files in, say, the archive director or any other directory.
Repeated.
Same result.
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a Live USB disk or did you install Ubuntu to the USB disk? If it's a live disk, be sure to reserve extra space or the drive will "reset" on each boot.

[image]